# Why $P(A|X=x) = x$ ? X that has a continuous distribution with $E(X) = 0.5$ and $σ(X) = 0.01$, A is define tails was obtained in a 1 toss of the coin

Tags: probability-distributions

A coin factory produces coins with a probability of getting “tails” X that has a continuous
distribution with expectation $0.5$ and standard deviation $0.01$.
A person chooses a random coin that is produced in the factory.
Suppose that event A is dependent on the value of continuous random variable X .
In this case the total probability formula to calculate the probability of event A is $ \int_{-∞}^{∞} P(A|X=x) f_x(x) \,dx $

We define the event:
A - “tails” was obtained in a single toss of the coin,

Why $P(A|X=x) = x$ ? It does not make sense because X represents the chance to get "tails" in each coin, so $P(A|X=x)$ represents the chance to get tails in a single toss we have given that $X=x$ , but $X=x$ should  represent a value of distribution function (which is unknown because we cannot identify how X distribute), isn't ?

Comment: Not following.  Saying that $X=x$ means that the probability of getting tails is $x$, right?   So your question asks for the probability of getting tails, conditioned on the fact that the probability of getting tails is $x$.  It doesn't matter how $X$ was chosen, if we know it is equal to $x$.

Comment: I don't know, it was a question in my exam and did not understand the wording at all. As you  say ,"X=x means that the probability of getting tails is x
, right?" it should not be  $P(X=x)$ ?

Comment: Yes,  the probability of getting that value for $X$ is irrelevant,  we're told that this is the value.  That's all that matters.

Comment: Yes, but also we know that for every X with continuous distribution  $P(X=x) = 0$ , so I completely don't understand what they want in that question

Comment: You should ask your instructor how they expect you to handle conditioning on an event with probability $0$.  In this case, I would say the answer was $x$, for the reasons I gave.  There is also a case to be made for saying it is ill-defined, since, if you write out the definition of conditional probability formally, you get $\frac 00$.

Comment: Just to illustrate, suppose $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.  Then, of course, $P(X=.5)=0$.  But I would still argue that $P(X=.5\,|\, X=.5)=1$ despite the apparent division by $0$.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) is a discussion on various ways to broaden the notion of conditional probability to (sometimes) permit conditioning on events of probability $0$.  Again, you should ask your instructor how they meant for you to handle it.